# Is the "ankle" on both sides of the foot?

Tags: word-choice

A little above of the foot, in both sides there are projections. One is from the inside of the led and the second is from the outside of the leg (I attached examples). My question is if the both sides are called "ankle" or just one of them?

I tried to get the information by googling but I didn't find clear answer for my question.

This picture shows the outside projection (of left leg):
[image: This picture shows the outside projection (of left leg)]

[![and this picture shows the internal side projection:

[image]

Comment: "The joint connecting the foot with the leg " OALD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the ankle is anywhere below the bottom of the shin and just above the heel. That includes both the interior and exterior sides of the foot, as well as the top part of the concave curve where the foot curves into the shin.

I would define the ankle region to be roughly anywhere in this oval (and this would apply to both sides of the foot as well):

[image]

Another way to think of it is that your ankle is the joint that allows your foot to move in several directions. It is made up of several bones, ligaments and tendons.

Some professions (like medicine) have very specific terms for the various parts of the ankle. See [this website](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2855022/) for some examples, like:

> *The anterior talofibular ligament plays an important role in limiting anterior displacement of the talus and plantar flexion of the ankle*.

<sup>(If that seems confusing, take heart! My fellow moderator MaulikV – who is a doctor – might understand that, but I don't.)</sup>

In day-to-day conversation, though, laypeople refer to the entire general region as the ankle. For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anklet) says:

> *An anklet is an ornament worn around the ankle*.

which shows how general the ankle can be:

[image]

**In short, most of the time, the ankle isn't just the projections on one side or the other, but the entire general area.**

Comment: Well, if I got you properly, generally they have the same name, but I can say "interior ankle" and "exterior ankle" in order to make a difference between them. Thank you

Comment: Update: I found that in the medical terminology they might be called: Medial malleolus and Lateral malleouls. see here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleolus

Comment: @Assiduous - Yes, you can say those terms. Conversationally, though, I think most people would just refer to these areas as _the inside of my ankle_ and _the outside of my ankle._ You might find [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+inside+of+*+ankle%2Cthe+interior+of+*+ankle&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) interesting to examine.